# Converting Belt Drive Bike With Paragon Sliders to Conventional Cassette

Tags: drivetrain, conversion, dropouts

My internal gear hub broke on tour in Kenya, and now I'll need to convert my bike to use locally available parts. The frame uses Paragon Machine Works sliding dropouts who makes [inserts](https://www.paragonmachineworks.com/hangers-inserts/adjustable-dropouts/sliding/right/10-mm/10-mm-right-side-insert-for-sliding-dropout-hanger-choose-color.html) which would give me a derailleur hanger and QR axle slot.

With these, will common Shimano parts fall into place? Square-taper BB will make things easy on the front. Still figuring out cable stops but will use something from [this answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/38406/whats-the-strongest-way-to-bond-a-cable-stop-to-an-aluminum-frame#40797).

[image: Paragon Sliding Dropout]

Comment: Or, is there a solution that doesn't involve international shipping?

Comment: Was this a rolhoff hub?

Comment: @Criggie Kindernay (now defunct). The Swap Cage (hub flange) broke and, as I've experienced before, will continue to break off flanges as until it's untrueable.

Comment: Machining a new Swap Cage would be ideal, but finding the resources seems equally challenging.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If what you have now is the plain "no hanger" drive side Paragon insert, there's not really a good way of getting a rear derailleur installed on to it.

Depending on the situation, it's entirely possible having someone fabricate you a functional insert would be much faster than getting one shipped. If there's industry around, it's likely you can find someone with a manual mill. Paragon uses 6061 (they don't specify the temper) but many good dropouts have been made out of 1020 plate, which is common and would likely be a safe, overbuilt choice here. Drawing out what what you have would be easy for someone used to doing machine shop work, as would be adding a hanger based on the publicly available specs for Shimano hangers that everyone in the bike industry copies, below.

[image]

Presuming manual machines (not CNC like Paragon) you'd probably wind up with some straight edges where the original has curvature, including at the slider interface. Since you won't need the adjustability in derailleur mode, that shouldn't matter. It matters a lot that the axle is located in a way that aligns properly with the NDS side.

If international shipping were to be needed either way, there could be a case for just getting a new duplicate IGH wheel (or perhaps hub and spokes) coming, unless for some reason you were worried about a repeat of whatever the problem was.

One of the things you'll need to consider if you are switching to RD is the availability of a touring-worthy wheel, or likewise a suitable quality rebuild of what you have with a derailleur hub.

You'll also need to figure out getting to a functional gearing range for your needs with whatever chainring/crank clearance constraints the bike might have. In terms of getting to a given high gear for a given chainring size at a given chainline, IGHs can do things that derailleur bikes can't in this regard, especially before the mainstreaming of 10-tooth cogs (it's unclear whether that's on the menu or relevant for you). If you are in a situation where clearance considerations are tight (i.e. any bike made to maximize tire clearance), things could get hairy with switching to RD, since in practice it can be hard to model or predict what will work and issues are often resolved by having parts on hand or easily obtainable to switch to. The reason this is a major concern is that Paragon implies custom, and custom IGH implies that unless it was made to be switchable to RD, there's potentially no reason for the builder to *not* give you the maximum tire clearance possible given whatever your target gear range was with the intended hub, depending on what the design priorities were. Instead, it's very possible the chainstays are taking up space you might otherwise want in the relevant area.

If none of the above is relevant, no there are no issues with just getting a Paragon RD insert and setting the bike up with whatever group. A lot of the recent FDs have integral stops so you may not need to worry about a clamp-on one, depending on what you're working with. Beyond that, doing full housings and zip-tying them on is likely a better plan than worrying about adding any other parts to route the cables.

Comment: Agreed, full housing works nicely and is very easy .

Comment: Very helpful response! Machining parts seems overly optimistic, but I'll ask around. Would someone stick-welding a piece on to the existing insert yield any value? TBH, I only vaguely understood your explanation of the limitations I'm facing. The issue with tire clearance means the rear wheel may be too far back for most chains? My chainstay length is 440mm.

Comment: @Laoshi Welding on to the existing insert may not be a great idea because Paragon uses 6061 of some heat treatment they don't publicly state, but after welding it will be back down to untempered strength. Basically the concern with clearance is that you could run into the issue that to get to a desired high gear with the derailleur setup, you might need to increase the size of the ring past what the bike can accomodate, depending on choices made in the design. IGH bikes can get to higher gears for a given chainring size, and some custom ones take advantage of that.

Comment: @NathanKnutson My chainstay has a dimple. Does this potentially work in favor of higher gears? Or are you talking about cassettes?

Comment: Dimples are there to create chainstay clearance. Another way of saying it is this: Using a gearing calculator, you probably want to identify your target high gear (i.e. in terms of gear inches or whatever method you prefer) then see what it would take for the various derailleur drivetrain possibilities to achieve it. As a precursor to this you probably want to use a gearing calculator that does Gates to note the gear range you're used to working with. (For touring the low end is more important generally, but I'm pointing out the above so it doesn't bite you at the last minute).